# Universal property of determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

Is there special name for morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $ \ \forall g:X \rightarrow Y \ \exists!h:Y \rightarrow Y \ (g = h\circ f)$? If there is no special name, can you give examples of such morphisms? Determinant $det:GL_{n}(K)\rightarrow K^{*}$ satisfy this property, and i'm trying to find other examples.

Comment: Needs more context.

Comment: @Jakobian, what do you mean?

Comment: You should include context or other details for this answer. This includes your tries, or just you giving us additional information about the things you are working with, that would motivate this question. As it stands, the question is too barren

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you mean by the determinant satisfying this property? What category are you working in? What morphism is the determinant?

Comment: @varkor, i mean that determinant $det:GL_{n}(K) \rightarrow K^{*}$ is unique up to endomorphism. So, it's category of groups.

Comment: This property looks reminiscent of the "prequasi-initial objects" of Tholen's [MacNeille completion of concrete categories with local properties](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/293149837.pdf), though that is a property of objects rather than of morphisms.

Comment: Define a category whose objects are the morphisms $f:X \to Y$ in some fixed category $C$ and whose morphisms $h:f \to g$ are the endomorphisms of $Y$ in $C$ for which $g=h \circ f$. Then, what you get is just an initial object in this category.

Comment: I probably mistaken, this definition doesn't define determinant in general case, with counterexamples in GL(C) - any composition of det and automorphism

Comment: Is there a homomorphism $GL_n(K) \to K^*$ whose kernel does not contain the special linear group?

Comment: @Geoffrey Trang. There isn't. I just want to say, that property doesn't define det unique. I didn't check, but as soon, as det is unique multilinear alternating map, $\overline{det(x)}$ - conjugation of det isn't multilinear alternating map, in case of $GL(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Well, one thing you can say is that the determinant map is the abelianization of the group $GL_n(K)$ -- with the single exception that $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ has abelianization isomorphic to $C_2 \not\simeq \mathbb{F}_2^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any name for this. As a generalization of your determinant example (modulo the single counterexample pointed out by Daniel Schepler), any abelianization $G \to G/[G, G]$ satisfies this condition in the category of groups, and more generally, if $C$ is any category and $D$ is any [reflective subcategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory) with reflection $R : C \to D$ (left adjoint to the inclusion $D \to C$), then the unit maps $c \to R(c)$ of the adjunction satisfy this condition, by the universal property of the reflection.